# Apply Function (MinCovDet) to a Pandas Dataframe rolling window (n x m array)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, apply

I want to calculate rolling robust covariance using sklearn.covariance MinCovDet.
I have a dataframe df with 3000 rows and 20 columns contain dates in the index. 
For each row to calculate the robust covariance over the let's say last 200 days.
I have tried with

```
df.apply(lambda x: MinCovDet().fit(df[x-400:x].values))
```

I get a TypeError: ("Cannot convert input [date\n2004-01-02 etc ...

Any idea? 
A more general question would be how to apply a function to a n x m array of a pandas Dataframe

Many thanks

Comment: A sample of your dataframe and the explicit error would make this easier. That said it looks like you are trying to fit MinCovDet on time stamps which would seem problematic.

Comment: values does not include the index, so there is something wrong with what you say.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the 'more general question'.

There is `pandas.DataFrame.rolling()` method specially for such cases: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Then you can use `.apply()` just as usual, or use the rolling object as an argument. So in your case the code will be the following:

```
MinCovDet.fit(df.rolling(window = 400).values)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are really the index, then they should not be seen by `df.values`. If the dates are the first column, then

```
df1 = df.loc[:, 1:]
df1.apply(lambda x: MinCovDet().fit(df[x-400:x].values))
```

should work fine.